# Update query has no effect

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to update a table, but no rows are affected:

```
$timing = array("7.00AM-9.00AM", "9.00AM-11.00AM", "6.30PM-9.00PM");       
$id = $_GET["id"];        
$batch = $_GET["d"];       
$i = array_search($batch, $timing);     
$set = "UPDATE tbl_reg SET timing = '".$timing[$i]."' WHERE reg_id = $id";    
$setexe = mysql_query($set);      
echo mysql_affected_rows($conn);       
$res = "alloted batch successfully";
```

When I manually put the same query into MySQL it works.

What is the problem?

Comment: Die and Dump the $i variable. Is $batch correctly referenced? Walk yourself through each set of instructions.

Comment: use echo $set; and check output...